# GIMP: How to create tints, shades, shadows of a colour

Tags: gimp, shadows

Once I have chosen a hue, how can I create a range of tints, shades and shadows?

Comment: I think you may need to be more specific. Are you creating like a color palette or something... or like just trying to figure out how to mix colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with GIMP in automatically way.
You can use some online tools or third party plugins.

Try Color Hexa ( http://www.colorhexa.com/ ), put your color in the search input and it returns color schemes, alternatives, shades and tints, tones and other useful related info.
Then you can create your palette in GIMP.